# Learning about bathymetry?

Tags: dem, elevation, topography, bathymetry

Besides reading about bathymetry, I would like to work on some hands-on training that I can learn about bathymetry. Is there any good bathymetry out there that I can get some training with the datasets?
I want to learn how it works and is it a good for small locate area or wide area ? What would I like to know the pros vs cons about using it for the Marine areas ?

Comment: Can you provide more specifics? What are you looking to learn about bathymetry? Any specific application in mind?

Comment: The Royal Australian Navy has released some bathymetric data http://www.ga.gov.au/metadata-gateway/metadata/record/74526/ that you can work with. It's from Geoscience Australia free of charge for educational purposes, just fill in the form and download it. None of it is anywhere near the U.S. but it's good data to learn with. I have found that bathymetric data is *very* hard to come by, especially less than 100m depth.

Answer (score 1):

[ArcGIS for Maritime](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/maritime/bathymetry): Bathymetry is a new component of the ArcGIS for Maritime platform available with the ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop release.

The software is developed for management and analysis of bathymetric data. [Digital Coast](http://coast.noaa.gov/digitalcoast/dataregistry/#/) is an excellent resource for such data. Not only is digital coast an excellent data resource it is also an excellent [training resource](http://coast.noaa.gov/digitalcoast/training/list/).

This is a nice little YouTube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkJ3okPD-_c). You can get a free 30-day trial of the extension and a 1-year version likely comes with some of the ESRI Press texts.